# TFS Server 2013 to Azure DevOps Server 2020

Tags: tfs

I need to migrate TFS 2013 to Azure Devops Server 2020. I could find that i need to upgrade to TFS 2015 before upgrading to Devops 2020 Server. Is there any option to migrate directly to Devops Server 2020 if i only need the Source code.

How can i migrate directly to Devops 2020 from TFS 2013.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

As it is clearly stated in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops-2020#before-you-upgrade-to-azure-devops-server-2020). You need to upgrade to TFS 2015 first.

> When upgrading your on-premises deployment to Azure DevOps Server 2020 you should be aware that upgrade from TFS 2015 and later versions are only supported. If you are using TFS 2013 or earlier versions, you need to upgrade to TFS 2015 first.

However, you can have a try using external migration tools to migrate from tfs 2013 to  Azure DevOps Server 2020 directly.

[Migration Tools for Azure DevOps](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/getting-started)

[Azure DevOps Server (TFS) – Azure DevOps Services (VSTS) Migration](https://www.opshub.com/migration-solutions/tfs-vsts-azure-devops-migration/)